# Очень странное поведение башни танка в Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

У меня есть танк с отдельным кодом для башни:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TowerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;

    public void LookAtXZ(Vector3 point, float speed)
    {
        var direction = (point - transform.position).normalized;
        direction.y = 0f;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(direction), speed);
    }

    void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.Find("Player");
    }

    void Update()
    {
        LookAtXZ(player.transform.position, 0.3f);
    }
}
```

Этот код должен поворачивать башню за игроком. И он в принципе работает. Но почему-то башня дополнительно поворачивается вверх:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это исправить?

UPD: Попробовал использовать: `transform.LookAt(player.transform.position);`. Ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Если код работает неправильно. Следует заняться его отладкой. Здесь вряд-ли кто-то будет дебажить Ваш код)

Comment: @artemgh Уже дебажу)

Comment: Держу за тебя кулачки

Comment: Вы, собственно, вращаете башню в сторону игрока по всем осям, вращайте ее только по оси Y (Нет у вас не сбита система координат, чтобы вращать объект влево-вправо, нужно изменять ось Y (погуглите  left handed coordinate system))

Comment: @KOTIK Погуглил, пробовал разные способы поворота. Но, у меня `x` башни в начале игры `-90f`, но `transform.LookAt()` почему-то поворачивает 'x' тоже, я пробовал использовать код поворачивающий только `y`, блокировать `x` с помощью `rigidbody`. Все равно `x` меняется.

Comment: @Bob ну да `transform.LookAt` делает так, чтобы `transform.forward` объекта был направлен на таргет, он вращает объект по всем осям. Вам нужно рассчитать угол, на который нужно повернуть объект по оси Y, чтобы он смотрел в сторону игрока и далее башню поворачивать на этот угол. Блокировать ничего не надо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел работающий код:

```
 using UnityEngine;
 public class TowerScript : MonoBehaviour
 {
     [SerializeField] Transform player;
     [SerializeField] Vector3 auxRotation = new Vector3( -90 , 0 , 0 );
     void Update ()
     {
         transform.LookAt(player.position );
         transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(auxRotation);
     }
 }
```